# Passing function references as parameters

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

Is it possible to pass a reference to a method as a parameter?

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "name: John, random text, address: leetStreet";
    Person person;

    //if regex matches, use method reference, to send the result. 
    applyDataToPerson(data, "name: (\\w+)", person, Person::setName);
    applyDataToPerson(data, "address: (\\w+)", person, Person::setAddress);
}

private static void applyDataToPerson(String data, String regex, Person person, 
 Function<Person> f) {
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(data);
    if (match.matches()) person.f(match.group(1));
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

If not, what would be an alternative to giving a reference to a method? Switch-case construct?

Comment: In Java 8 you can [pass method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to existing methods (among other things)

Comment: @Tibrogargan how would the method signature look like? `Comparator <? super T>` does not make sense to me.

Comment: What is `Function<Person>` supposed to represent? If we're talking about [`java.util.function.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), it has 2 generic types, not 1. So that code cannot compile to begin with... (let alone `person.f(...)`). Before asking for _alternatives_, make sure you have working code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html):

```
private static void applyDataToPerson(String data, String regex, Person person, BiConsumer<Person, String> action) {
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(data);
    if (match.matches()) action.accept(person, match.group(1));
}
```

Alternatively, you can shorten the method signature and use a single-argument [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) that captures your `person` reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "name: John, random text, address: leetStreet";
    Person person;

    //if regex matches, use method reference, to send the result. 
    applyData(data, "name: (\\w+)", person::setName);
    applyData(data, "address: (\\w+)", person::setAddress);
}

private static void applyData(String data, String regex, Consumer<String> action) {
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(data);
    if (match.matches()) action.accept(match.group(1));
}
```

Comment: And in your main method write the biconsumer function : `applyDataToPerson(data, "name: (\\w+)", person, (Person p, String s) -> p.setName(s) );
        applyDataToPerson(data, "address: (\\w+)", person, (Person p,String s) -> p.setAddress(s));`

Comment: @gaston No, the main method is exactly as OP had it.

Comment: Personally I like the second option.